# What is the difference between these characters?

Tags: duplicates

What is the difference between `"` and `''` and ``` `` ```?

Additionally, which one should be used in string quotes? (Java)

Comment: What programming language? That can be pretty important.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is certainly not about programming and I am not sure whether it can be on topic for "English language usage" site or not..

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 - single- and double-quoted - stem from the language C / C++.

`" "` - double-quoted quotation marks usually are for strings.

Example:

`String hello = "Hello";`

`' '` - single-quoted quotation marks are for chars.

Example:

`Char h = 'h';`

Note: They can also be used to show an escape sequence: `char a = '\t';`

``` `` ``` - these are called backticks or backquotes and are mostly used for enclosing identifiers. They dont appear too often in java, but more in other languages like PHP or with databases.

Their origin is quite interesting:

> From the point of view of English usage, there is no difference other
>   than appearance between the "backtick" (`) and the single quote mark
>   ('). The characters exist in these forms because of compromises made
>   in older computer character sets. Preceding computers, there is a long
>   history in printing typography of using slightly different shapes for
>   the opening and closing single quotes. In the more modern computer
>   character set known as Unicode, there are new codes for these curved
>   marks, the left (‘) and right (’) single quotes. Because of various
>   problems with computers, a mix of all four single quote characters may
>   be found, but should be considered equivalent (except for their visual
>   appearance).

Source: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/any-reference-on-the-usage-of-a-backtick-and-single-quotation-mark-like-this

Comment: Does this answer your question? If yes please accept my answer. If not we could look into more details. :)